# prove that a sequence of functions does not converge pointwise by definition

Tags: calculus

I have the following Question:
Given the following sequence of functions: $\{f_{n}( x)\}_{n=1}^{\infty } =\{\cos( nx)\}_{n=1}^{\infty } $ does it converge pointwise in this domain : $[ 0,\pi ]$?

Attempt:

looking at  $x=\pi$ whenever $n=odd$ $\cos(n\pi)=-1$, and whenever $n=even$ we get $\cos(n\pi)=1$.

That resembles the series $(-1)^n$ which diverges, that means that when $x=\pi$ the function doesn't converge pointwise that is why the series doesn't converge pointwise

I wanted to disprove the pointwise convergence by definition and I got stuck, is there a way to do it ?

also, does my attempt prove that it doesn't converge ?

Comment: Your counterexample shows that the sequence doesn't converge pointwise in $[0,\pi]$. Note that it *does* converge pointwise at $x=0$. It might be interesting to investigate whether there are any other points in $[0,\pi]$ where the sequence converges pointwise.

Comment: Is this a question concerning series (as in the title of the question) or about sequences (as in the body)?

Comment: It is concerning the sequence in the body, ill edit the title

Comment: You are correct. To say that $(f_n)_n$ converges pointwise on $[0,\pi]$ is just an abbreviated way to say that $\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x)$ exists for each $x\in [0,\pi].$  To disprove this, it suffices to exhibit just one  $x\in [0,\pi]$ (e.g. $x=\pi$) where $\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x)$ does not exist.